# contract from other project than interface not visible

Tags: .net, wcf

When I add to project a wcf service I could see it under Add Service Reference.
But after move interface to another project, but the same namespace and type proper reference in contract to interface - I can not see my service under Add Service Reference.

Why? I miss something in config file ?

Service Config file should be in project with interface or contract ?

edit.

First project

```
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace Project.ServiceModel
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();
    }
}
```

Second project

```
using Project.ServiceModel;

namespace Project.Service
{
    public class Test : ITest
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And that configuration in Test class project

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Project.Service.Test">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Test/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      contract="Project.ServiceModel.ITest">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/LMTService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to the project with the interface to your service?

Comment: interface = contract. clarify your question please and give some code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `contract="Project.ServiceModel.ITest"` to reference a fully qualified name (including assembly name, not only namespace). Like `contract="Project.ServiceModel.ITest, Project.ServiceModel"`, given your project name is `Project.ServiceModel` and assembly name is set up to be the same as project name (that's usually so by default).

And maybe it is a typo, but your mex address looks incorrect. Should be `http://localhost:8732/Test/mex`. It will still probably work with your current configuration, but you're breaking a convention.

Comment: When I use WCF Servise Host Tool it show error "The service cannot be started. This service has no endpoint defined. Please add at least one endpoint for the service in config file and try again." But as You see below I have endpoint! ;/

Comment: I solve problem! I set behaviorConfiguration to endpoint , not to service!